# RobotFramework - how to write code to bypass cloudflare authentication using service token (client id) and Client secret) to access a website

Tags: robotframework, cloudflare

need help, i need robotframework sample or example for bypassing the cloudflare authentication to access an url using service token (CF-Access-Client-Id:  CF-Access-Client-Secret: ) passing in header

current case:
i have url -  xx@yy.zz after access it.
(CloudFlare authentication) asks for email id and after inputing the email id it sends OTP to mobile
inputing the OTP then i am able to access the url

i found a way for bypassing authentication using service token.
https://developers.cloudflare.com/access/access-service-auth/service-tokens

but i am not sure how do i pass this service token in robotframework

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `CF-Access-Client-Id` and `CF-Access-Client-Secret` on the headers:

```
CF-Access-Client-Id: your-client-id
CF-Access-Client-Secret: your-client-secret
```

so your request mustbe like this

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "url": "https://example.com/",
  "queryString": [],
  "headers": [
    {
      "name": "CF-Access-Client-Id",
      "value": "your-client-id"
    },
    {
      "name": "CF-Access-Client-Secret",
      "value": "your-client-secret"
    }
  ]
}
```

if you want when user not provide or not valid `CF-Access-Client-Id` and `CF-Access-Client-Secret` on header then just do regular authentication, then you have to add multiple policy.

1. policy for `Service Token` with action `Service Auth`.
2. whatever you want, for example allow login with email then just add policy with type action `Allow`.